# Choose numbers which sum to zero

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

There is N number of sets, each containing various number of integers, e.g.:

```
(-2, -1, 0), (-1,4), (-2, 2, 3), (-3, -2, 4, 6), (-2)
```

How to pick exactly one number from each set so that these N integers sum to zero? For example:

```
-1, -1, 2, -2, 4, -2
```

Note there might be no solution or multiple (in which case it doesn't matter which one I choose).

I was thinking that I can do breath-first search but was wondering if there are any other, preferably faster, ways to solve this.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: You might want to fix your example solution.

Comment: Elliot: no, Don: thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `dp[i, j] = true` iff we can make sum `j` using one number from each of the sets `1, 2, ..., i`.

```
dp[i, 0] = true for all i
for i = 1 to numSets do
  for num = 1 to sets[i].Count do
    for j = maxSum - sets[i, num] downto -maxSum do
      dp[i, j + sets[i, num]] |= dp[i - 1, j]
```

You can use a map to handle negative indexes or add an offset to make them positive. `maxSum` is the maximum value your sum can take (for example sum of maximums of all sets or sum of absolute values of minimums, whichever is larger). There might be ways to update `maxSum` as you go as an optimization.

For your example, this will run like so:

```
(-2, -1, 0), (-1,4), (-2, 2, 3), (-3, -2, 4, 6), (-2)
```

Iteration over the first set will give `dp[1, -2] = dp[1, -1] = dp[1, 0] = true`.

Iteration over the second will give `dp[2, -3] = true (because dp[2, -2 + -1] |= dp[1, -1] = true), dp[2, -2] = true (because dp[2, -1 + -1] |= dp[1, -1] = true`) etc.

If `dp[numSets, 0] = true`, there is a solution, which you can reconstruct by keeping tracking of which last number you picked for each `dp[i, j]`.

The complexity is `O(numSets * K * maxSum)`, where `K` is the number of elements of a set. This is pseudopolynomial. It might be fast enough if your values are small. If your values are large but you have few sets with few elements, you are better off bruteforcing it using backtracking.

Comment: I just wanted to add one more information above - what if I knew the largest and the smallest integer, would it help? If I'm not mistaken, your solution takes advantage exactly this fact, am I right? And "dp" stands for "dynamic programming"?

Comment: @EcirHana - no, I don't see how knowing the smallest and largest integer helps. You need to know the sum of the minimums and the sum of the maximums, and take the max of their absolute values. Yes, dp = dynamic programming.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to extend this approach to real numbers? I mean, If the sets contained floats, instead of ints?

Comment: With the max and min I thought that if you can guarantee their sizes, you can use array to store the intermediate sums. Otherwise K could be very, very large, i.e. the algorithm might run in polynomial time, but with a huge constant. But maybe I misunderstood...

Comment: @EcirHana - Only if you turn the floats into ints by multiplying them with a power of 10. `K` can get very large indeed, there is no helping that. The algorithm is pseudopolynomial, just like the subset sum DP algorithm. If you have large values, this won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

This seems related to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem): given a set *n* integers, is there a subset that sums to 0? That problem is known to be [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and that, in short, means your chances are very small of finding a fast way of doing this.

For one set of integers it's hard enough and in your problem another constraint is added that one integer must be selected from each set. A search algorithm is indeed the way to go but in the worst case you won't be doing much better than an exhaustive search.

Comment: I thought that it should be easier to solve because of the N since it shrinks the search-space..?

Comment: It's true that one integer has to be selected from each set and not an unknown number of integers from a single set but for large N, the search space still blows up. The number of possibilities is (size of set_1) times (size of set_2) times ... times ... (size of set_n) and that can still be huge. Also, the subset sum problems looks deceptively easy to solve but it turns out it's not. I'm not sure if there is a "fast" way of solving your version of the problem.