# How to carry out operations on random amount of lists which contain random amount of elements

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-structures, linked-list

I've got a number of LInked Lists, where the number of linked lists is in theory random, as I can have an unspecified amount. The amount of elements inside each list can also be any amount. Basically, I can have a random amount of lists, with a random number of elements like the following:

**List 1**

- 1
- 34
- 91

**List 2**

- 6
- 5
- 94
- 43
- 245
- 467

**List 3**

- 98
- 39

**List 4**

- 11

And so on...

What I'd like to do is check if any combination of elements in every single list added together is equal to a certain value.

For example, element 1 in `List 1` + element 5 in `List 2` + element 2 in `List 3` + element 1 in `List 4` = a certain value. What I want is all the combinations of lists which follow a previous one, i.e. it must be list 1 + list 2 + .... list n, in order.

Could anyone suggest how this could be achieved?

Comment: If it were homework, I'd tag it appropriately. Just because I break down a problem and try to simplify it for a better chance at getting help, it does not make it homework.

Comment: Looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754302/choose-numbers-which-sum-to-zero . It's not C# specific, but conceptually the problem looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

If what you say is: take a single int from every list and see if their sum is equal to something then

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 34, 91});
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 6, 5, 94, 43, 245, 467 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 98, 39 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 11 });

var cp = CartesianProduct(lists);
int searchFor = 115;
foreach (var list in cp)
{
    if (list.Sum() == searchFor)
    {
        foreach (var i in list) Console.Write(i + " ");
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new IEnumerable<T>[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
        {
            return accumulator.SelectMany(
                (accseq => sequence),
                (accseq, item) => accseq.Concat(new T[] { item })
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const int SearchedValue = 296;
static List<LinkedList<int>> lists;
static Stack<int> indexes = new Stack<int>();

private static void Check(int sum, int listIndex)
{
    if (listIndex == lists.Count)
    {
        if (sum == SearchedValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found: " + String.Join(", ",
                indexes.Reverse().Select(i => i + 1).ToArray()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var value in lists[listIndex])
        {
            indexes.Push(i++);
            Check(sum + value, listIndex + 1);
            indexes.Pop();
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var list1 = new LinkedList<int>();
    list1.AddLast(1);
    list1.AddLast(34);
    list1.AddLast(91);

    var list2 = new LinkedList<int>();
    list2.AddLast(6);
    list2.AddLast(5);
    list2.AddLast(94);
    list2.AddLast(43);
    list2.AddLast(245);
    list2.AddLast(467);

    var list3 = new LinkedList<int>();
    list3.AddLast(98);
    list3.AddLast(39);

    var list4 = new LinkedList<int>();
    list4.AddLast(11);

    lists = new List<LinkedList<int>>() { list1, list2, list3, list4 };

    Check(0, 0);
}
```